# "Don't tell this your math teacher" - Why?

Tags: derivatives, physics

Physicists often deal with equations like $dW = dq(V_a - V_b)$ and say "Don't tell this your math teacher" when they do $\frac {dW}{dt} = \frac {dq}{dt}(V_a - V_b)$. But why is it so dangerous to differentiate against time?

Comment: It's not. It's dangerous to "divide" by $dt$.

Comment: @Arthur Unless you are Abraham Robinson. Then it's okay. :)

Comment: Pesky side note: it is **differentiate** not **derive**.

Comment: They are often dealing with multivariate functions and the $dy$ actually refers to an infinitesimal change $\delta y$. Only later is the "derivative" actually taken, if one does exist.

Comment: No one asked me, but it has always scared me how physicists use differentials.  I mean, I'm sure it's fine, but...

Comment: @Randall I don't know---I kind of like the notation $\int \mathrm{d}x f(x)$ for the integral of $f$.  It treats $\int\mathrm{d}x$ as the operator that it always wanted to be.

Comment: That doesn't bother me.

Comment: @Randall Neither me. The plasticity of Leibniz notations (dx, dy,dx/dy...) explains the huge progresses accomplished in the18th century, either on the mathematics side or on the physics side. This is still true, even in mathematical research, where "infinitesimal thinking" in the 18th century style, can help a lot. Look at the writings of Poincaré, one of the last to have been a great mathematician and a great physicist: he uses differentials, for example for building modern thermodynamics theory, in a very intuistic manner.

Comment: @JeanMarie I would also suggest looking at Abraham Robinson's non-standard analysis.  It is a much more recent (and quite successful) attempt at making the 17th century intuition rigorous to a 20th century standard.  With a bit of care, infinitesimal thinking can be made quite rigorous.

Comment: @Xander Henderson You are right, I should have mentionned it.